# How to create a procedure that shows a table (select * from emp)

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to create a procedure on **PL/SQL** that only shows the (**select * from emp**) from my SQL table.

I am learning about procedures and I can basically change and update the table, but I want to show the modifications I made.

Comment: Where do you wanna show that? Just at stdout?

Comment: @TobiSH Yes at stdout.

Comment: Maybe `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` is your friend. Just run the query iterate over the results and use this function to write to stdout. Maybe this helps: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_output.htm#BABJCAJA

Comment: Procedures aren't meant to return results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one option - ref cursor returned as an OUT parameter.

```
SQL> create or replace procedure p_test (par_out out sys_refcursor) as
  2  begin
  3    open par_out for select * From dept;
  4  end;
  5  /

Procedure created.

SQL> var rc refcursor
SQL>
SQL> exec p_test(:rc);

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> print rc

    DEPTNO DNAME                LOC
---------- -------------------- --------------------
        10 ACCOUNTING           NEW YORK
        20 RESEARCH             DALLAS
        30 SALES                CHICAGO
        40 OPERATIONS           BOSTON

SQL>
```

Comment: Or use `DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT()`

Answer (score 4):

Or just use SQL.

```
select * from emp
```

Adding PL/SQL to the mix doesn't really get you anything. If anything, it could make things harder/slower.

In SQL Server it's quite common to use T-SQL procedures to nothing but selects and return query results. This is not so common in Oracle.

You most definitely CAN use PL/SQL to execute SQL - but then you would generally do something WITH those results, with the logic in your PL/SQL. And then you would do something with those results - perhaps put them in a new object/table, or return a subset of them with a message to the caller of your PL/SQL program.

But if you are truly ONLY running a SQL and you want to get the results, then see Littlefoot's answer. Just be aware that going from PL/SQL to SQL, there's often a context switch at the Oracle optimizer/engine level, and there could be a performance hit.

To your question - how to see JUST the changes you made. See the RETURNING clause. T[here are some good examples here that show how to make changes AND get back said changes all in one code block..with plsql](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/content_C3DBYO1P9SPL57Y0128NCP1KL.html). In particular see statement/example 7.

Comment: Thanks for the link! I know how to show that on SQL hahah. I want to create a procedure that for instance would update the salary ( which I know how to do ) but as well show the changes I made instead of going to SQL `select * from emp` then run the procedure then come back to SQL again so I can see the results.

Comment: Understood, can you edit your question to show how you're changing the data? Then we can give you a better answer. Like, one row or many? Insert or update?

Answer (score 2):

If you're just getting started, then DBMS_OUTPUT is your friend to output *anything* from the database to your client program.

So you might just to just loop around the rows in your table, eg

```
SQL> set serverout on
SQL> begin
  2    for i in ( select * from emp )
  3    loop
  4      dbms_output.put_line(i.empno||'-'||i.ename);
  5    end loop;
  6  end;
  7  /
7369-SMITH
7499-ALLEN
7521-WARD
7566-JONES
7654-MARTIN
7698-BLAKE
7782-CLARK
7788-SCOTT
7839-KING
7844-TURNER
7876-ADAMS
7900-JAMES
7902-FORD
7934-MILLER

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

But, if you're starting out on the PL/SQL journey its time to grab a book on it, or head on over to devgym.oracle.com and livesql.oracle.com for assistance and tutorials.

Welcome to the PL/SQL club!

As Jeff said, when you get into some "real" programming, it can an easy temptation to use PL/SQL code where simply a SQL statement would do.  So once you've learned some more PLSQL, ensure you don't use it to "reinvent the wheel" so to speak. PL/SQL is used to *extend* what SQL can, not replace it.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah I'm reading a book about PL/SQL. I'm not trying to reinvent the wheel hahah that's unfortunately homework.

Answer (score 0):

**Try This **

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION DBFUN_RETURN_TABDATA RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR IS
REC_TAB SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
    OPEN REC_TAB FOR SELECT * FROM SCOTT.EMP;
    RETURN REC_TAB;
END;
```